# How to dynamically generate HTML with Blade

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

In Laravel 5 and Blade, I'm using a form with a textarea to store text in a mysql database and then display it back out to the user. I want to be able to preserve the carriage returns. I tried the simple approach of using the nl2br() 
function which replaces the \r\n with 
 tags:

```
public function setBodyAttribute($data){

    $this->attributes['body'] = nl2br($data);

}
```

It seems that Blade won't allow html to be displayed as HTML.

```
{{ $example->body }}
```

What is the best way to get around this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since you mentioned Laravel 5, you're looking for:

```
{!! $example->body !!}
```

In Laravel 4, `{{ $data }}` would echo data as is, whereas `{{{ $data }}}` would echo data after running it through `htmlentities`.

However, Laravel 5 has changed it so that `{{ $data }}` will echo data after running it through `htmlentities`, and the new syntax `{!! $data !!}` will echo data as is.

Documentation [here](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/templates#other-blade-control-structures).